# Meeting invite ics showing as attachment in office 365

Tags: coldfusion, icalendar, coldfusion-2016

When I send an appointment (ics file), it shows up correctly in Outlook, gmail but in Office 365, it shows up as an attachment though it shows the option of Add to Calendar but it does not shows the preview neither the RSVP.

Comment: I am using CF2016 and my invites are not even showing up in the emails. It's like the email doesn't even have a calendar part. Are you sending ics as cfmailparam ?

Comment: @SimranjitSingh, yes I send it as cfmailparam. <cfmailparam file="#calFileLocation#\iCal#wsUUID#.ics" disposition="inline" type="text/calendar" remove="true">